# Lambda with nested if else is not working

Tags: python, lambda

I'm newbie to Python and am learning `lambda` expressions at the moment. I was solving a tutorial program

> Define a function `max_of_three()` that takes three numbers as arguments
>   and returns the largest of them.

I've gone through this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/python-putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line) and tried without success:

```
>>> max_of_three = lambda x, y, z : x if x > y else (y if y>z  else z)
>>> max_of_three(91,2,322)
91
```

Why it's not returning Z?  It's X.

Comment: Look at your logic closely. X is bigger than Y, so it returns X.

Comment: Elaborating on what Morgan explained: It never gets to your else...

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambdas.

Comment: Not the problem with your function, but there is a builtin `max` function you could use: `max_of_three = lambda x, y, z : max(x,y,z)`

Comment: max (x, y, z) or something like x if x > y and x > z else y if y > z else z

Comment: @Trengot you could answer it instead of comment

Comment: @VigneshKalai, it didn't really answer the question of why the original code didn't work. Bruce has now answered with the same thing.

Comment: @Trengot it is always acceptable if you provide a method better then the OP's but never mind it has been answered

Comment: @Trengot : I've seen your comment /after/ posting mine, kudos for being first one :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently you are using `if x > y` which only compares the `x` and `y`, but you need to compare the `x` with `z` as well at the same step.

```
max_of_three = lambda x, y, z: x if x > y and x > z else (y if y > z else z)
print max_of_three(91, 2, 322)
>>> 322
```

Answer (score 5):

or, make it simpler:

```
max_of_three=lambda x,y,z:max((x,y,z))

max_of_three(1,2,3)
3
```

I know it's cheating, but using the language primitives is usually easier :-)

Comment: One of the great advantages of python  is that it has countless libraries and functions for _almost_ every problem. Hence, i'd rather read documentation such as numpy or scipy and apply it to my problem than starting from scratch. (in short: +1)

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your function as follows:

```
max_of_three = lambda x, y, z : x if x > y and x > z else (y if y>z  else z)
```

Your problem was that you did not check, whether `x` is also larger than `z`. In your case `x` is larger than `y`, therefore, it just returns `x` and does not compare it to `z` anymore.