# More info on one line if-else statements in python

Tags: python-3.x

[Putting an if-elif-else statement on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line) did not give me enough information figure out my problem. I want to turn

```
if pointer == 0:
    quit(print("ERROR:POINTER VALUE < 0"))
else:
    pointer -=1
```

into a one line if statement so I can put it in an `exec()` statement. Please elaborate on the info provided in the linked question

Comment: What did you try writing?

Comment: `'quit(print("ERROR:POINTER VALUE < 0")) if pointer == 0 else pointer -=1'`

Comment: The link you referenced will only work for assigning 2 (or more) different values to a variable. I think @Nick Frost's answer should work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` doesn't actually need its argument to be in one line. You can pass it a multi-line string.

```
exec('if a:\n print("true")\nelse:\n print("false")')
```

Comment: That was actually one of the things I tried. It did not work as I intended

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator.

Here is a better explanation -
[Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Read up on the wikipedia entry here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Basically, it's a way to write a conditional when you have only two possible results for boolean comparison. It's great for very short lines.

For example:

```
x = 5 if True else x = 4
x = 1 if x == 0 else y = 10/x
```

In your case, it may not be the best decision, as your line will grow pretty long.

Comment: will `'quit(print("ERROR:POINTER VALUE < 0")) if pointer == 0 else pointer -=1'` work?

Comment: Your best bet might be to wrap all of the meat into a function. Then call the function in exec()