# how to write If elif else in one line python

Tags: python-3.x

```
                        if CheckRadioHigh is True:
                            Higher_Lower = 'Higher'
                        elif CheckRadioLower is True:
                            Higher_Lower = 'Lower'
                        else:
                            Higher_Lower = ''
```

I want to write this line of code in one line / short hand format.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line  this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Can do this by nesting `if-else` oneliners:

```
Higher_Lower = 'Higher' if CheckRadioHigh else ('Lower' if CheckRadioLower else '')
```

**Please note:** You do not have to explicitly check a boolean variable if it `is True` or `is False` in `if` statements. Just make use of the content of the variable by checking `if <boolean variable>`.

Comment: Do you really need the parentheses though?

Comment: No, actually you don't. But i'd keep them for readability. Just personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

```
Higher_Lower = 'Higher' if CheckRadioHigh else 'Lower' if CheckRadioLower else 'Do some searching buddy :)'
```