# How to use python generators with multiple if statements?

Tags: python, generator

say something basic like:

```
def fizzBuzz(n: int) -> List[str]:
        l =[]
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if i%3==0 and i%5==0:
                l.append("FizzBuzz")
            elif i%3==0:
                l.append("Fizz")
            elif i%5==0:
                l.append("Buzz")
            else:
                l.append(str(i))
        return l
```

where input: n=15.
output: [
"1",
"2",
"Fizz",
"4",
"Buzz",
"Fizz",
"7",
"8",
"Fizz",
"Buzz",
"11",
"Fizz",
"13",
"14",
"FizzBuzz"
]
I have started with something like:

```
["FizzBuzz" if x%3 ==0 and x%5==0 else str(x) for x in range(1, n+1)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting an if-elif-else statement on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line)

Comment: better answer. https://leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz/discuss/89928/Python-Golf

Comment: `[("Fizz" * (not i % 3) + "Buzz" * (not i % 5)) or str(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]` *If you will use parentheses instead of brackets, you will get a generator*

Comment: @venky__, funny that I've written almost same list comprehension with last example from your link without actually opening it :D

Comment: @OlvinRoght  using `int` here is redundant, since booleans are integers in Python ;-) (Ah, it's edited now)

Comment: Also you can replace `[]` by `()` since he asked for a generator and you can remove the `()` around the `+` since it takes precedence over `or` ;-)

Comment: @LucasMoeskops, read the text after code example ;-) And I left parentheses for better readability.

Comment: while it's doable, then [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) tell us it's a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for a generator, here is your function converted to one, along with usage.

Notice that `fizz_buzz(n)` returns a NEW generator, so if you want multiple iterations, you would have to generate a new one every time.

```
n = 15


def fizz_buzz(n: int):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            yield "FizzBuzz"
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            yield "Fizz"
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            yield "Buzz"
        else:
            yield str(i)


a = fizz_buzz(n)
for f in a:
    print(f)
```

Output:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> Fizz
> 4
> Buzz
> Fizz
> 7
> 8
> Fizz
> Buzz
> 11
> Fizz
> 13
> 14
> FizzBuzz
> ```

---

However **you may have wanted a list comprehension one liner**, and didn't know what it is called and assumed the name was a "generator".

In that case,

```
b = ["FizzBuzz" if i%3==0 and i%5==0 else "Fizz" if i%3==0 else "Buzz" if i%5==0 else str(i) for i in range(n)]
print(b)
```

And, this can also be a **one-liner-generator**:

```
c = ("FizzBuzz" if i%3==0 and i%5==0 else "Fizz" if i%3==0 else "Buzz" if i%5==0 else str(i) for i in range(n))
for f in c:
    print(f)
```

Comment: note that `i%3==0 and i%5==0` is equivalent to `i%15==0`

Comment: @CyrilJouve correct, but beats the purpose of modularity, readability and simplicity. The main question here is "What is 15?".  what if the numbers stop being 3 and 5, but `m` and `n`? now "FizzBuzz" would check for `n*m`, which would be stored in an extra variable because it needs a name. I recommend this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LueeMTTDePg

Comment: @CyrilJouve I meant this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsHMHukIlJY linked the wrong one last time