# How to use elif in ternary operators in python?

Tags: python

I want to use elif in ternary operator, but it does not work. Is there any workaround?

```
"a" if x >= 90 "b" elif x >= 60 else "c"
```

Comment: You can nest them. I guess `"a" if x >= 90 else "b" if x >= 60 else "c"` would work, although not good for readability.

Comment: You might want to look up the definition of ternary before using that term. Java has a ternary expression. So called because it has 3 parts. Python does have this useful construct but it's not a ternary expression

Comment: The term is "ternary *operator*" because it's a single operator that takes 3 operands, the operator in Java being `? ... :` rather than a contiguous string. There's really no *technical* reason why `... if ... else ...` couldn't be called a ternary operator for the same reason. Operators usually consist of non-alphanumeric characters like `+` and `*=`, but Python happily refers to `is`, `is not`, `in`, and `not in` as operators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting an if-elif-else statement on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029245/putting-an-if-elif-else-statement-on-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an elif in a ternary operator. You can, however, do a chained ternary like:

```
i=15
x = 10 if i <15 else 1 if i > 15 else 0
```

I'm not saying a long chain like this is always recommended, though; you shouldn't really sacrifice readability to cut down on your line count.

Answer (score 0):

You chain another ternary on the end to do the `elif` portion; however, readability takes a nose dive.

[Further reading from this blog after I Googled 'how to do elif in python ternary operations'](https://blog.finxter.com/python-ternary-elif/)

```py
print("not equal") if some_condition != some_other else print("greater") if some_condition >= some_other else print("other thing")
```